# "He ate apples, throwing away their cores"- Does it make sense?

Tags: sentence-construction

I made a sentence:

> He ate apples, throwing away their cores.

Does this make sense as:

> He ate apples and then threw away their cores

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about actions that take place at the same time or in sequence.

In most cases, the present participle (the -ing form) indicates that two actions occur at the same time. (At least, that is the convention we are taught in school.) Consider:

> Walking down the street, I saw a horse.

This means that I saw the horse **while** I was walking down the street—not before, not after.

Careful editors will therefore object to a sentence like this:

> Walking down the street, I jumped onto a bicycle and rode away.

It is impossible to walk and ride a bicycle at the same time, so this sentence violates the convention.

But this does not mean that it doesn't make sense. If you said this in a casual conversation, your listeners would understand that you are describing a *sequence* of events.

Your sentence is a little different. It takes time to eat multiple apples—20 minutes or more, perhaps. We can think of it as a process rather than an event. Many things can happen during the course of a process. You could sing a song. You could drive your car from home to a store. All that stuff can happen at the same time.

You could certainly throw away each apple core after you ate the apple, and your listeners would imagine each throw taking place *during* the process of eating the apples.

In short: your sentence makes perfect sense if we follow the rules we are taught in school *or* if we imagine the events occurring in a sequence.

I doubt that even a book editor would object. It sounds like a sentence that Hemingway might have written.

> Nick ate the apples slowly, throwing away the cores and thinking about the good place.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense but is really more than needed. It would really only be worth commenting on if he ate the apple whole as most people don't eat the core. Or maybe instead of throwing them out he puts them on a window sill to dry and later uses them for Christmas tree ornaments. But as long as it's what people usually do it's kind of pointless to include.

If a sentence were "His breakfast that morning was limited to a couple apples." I would simply assume the cores were disposed of in some manner.

Comment: Well, true I suppose. Without knowing the larger context it's hard to say if the part about throwing away the cores is relevant. If the next paragraph is about racoons finding the cores or about his trash being filled with apple cores or whatever, it could be extremely relevant. Or if you've just said that he lives in a society where people routinely eat apple cores or save them for some reason. If it's never brought up again, sure, probably a superfluous point.